# Why serialize return stdClass? (PHP)

Tags: php, json

i have one json but when i using serialize() return stdclass?

```
$json= [{"lt":"1","lot":["0","1","0"]},{"lt":"2","lot":["0","0","0"]}]
```

and this after serialize():

```
a:2:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:2:"lt";s:1:"1";s:3:"lot";a:3:{i:0;s:1:"0";i:1;s:1:"1";i:2;s:1:"0";}}i:1;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:2:"lt";s:1:"2";s:3:"lot";a:3:{i:0;s:1:"0";i:1;s:1:"0";i:2;s:1:"0";}}}
```

i need like this but i cant solve it:

```
a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:"lt";s:1:"1";s:3:"lot";a:3:{i:0;s:1:"0";i:1;s:1:"1";i:2;s:1:"0";}}i:1;a:2:{s:2:"lt";s:1:"2";s:3:"lot";a:3:{i:0;s:1:"0";i:1;s:1:"0";i:2;s:1:"0";}}}
```

Comment: use the `true` flag in `_decode`

Comment: `echo serialize(json_decode($json, 1));`

Comment: The [PHP Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for `json_decode()` explains this clearly

Comment: Your first line is invalid PHP ~ *"Parse error: parse error, expecting `']''"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try

```
serialize(json_decode($json, true));
```